# mkdir in ftp using shell script if folder doesn't exist

Tags: shell, ftp, mkdir

I'm a newbie to FTP. I want to create a folder if it doesn't exists already.
I know there is an option "mkdir -p foldername", but doing this in ftp creates a folder by the name "-p".
I'm trying to transfer files from one remote server to another via ftp and create folders in receiving server if not already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to always attempt to create the folder - and then ignore any errors. Of course, after creating the folder you need to `cd` into it - if that gives an error then you've got bigger problems.

The `-p` option in the shell `mkdir` is there to ensure no error is raised. FTP doesn't use the shell: it does it for itself.

Comment: I was silly. I was doing something wrong and was assuming mkdir is not creating a new folder if it doesn't existed. Thanks mate!